# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier: - when using node express's response.locals value inside <script>

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I was trying to access a variable added to node express's res.locals from index.hbs within a `<script>` tag.

Express code

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.locals.settings = {active: true};
 render(req, res, 'dist/index.hbs');
});
```

Using res.locals inside `<script>` tag in hbs file.

```
 <body>
    ....
      rendered html
    ....

    <script type="text/javascript">
       somefunction(JSON.stringify({{{settings}}});
    </script>
</body>
```

While loading the page, an error is thrown.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

[image]

Comment: `{{settings}}` instead of `{{{settings}}}` ?

Comment: @MukeshSharma I tried both `{{settings}}` and `{{{settings}}}` options, gives the same error. Even tried with and without the  JSON.stringify()

Comment: You can try `res.locals.settings = JSON.stringify({active: true});`

Comment: @MukeshSharma Even tried that as well. Didn't make any difference.